# Better way of selecting rows where a month falls between start and end date

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Suppose the month to be considered is `Oct 2013` and I want to pull all rows in which `October 2013` falls between start and end date.

I'm currently using this in my `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (start_date >= '2013-10-01' AND end_date < '2013-11-01') OR // between 1st and 31st
      (start_date >= '2013-10-01' AND start_date < '2013-11-01') OR // start falls in oct'13
      (end_date >= '2013-10-01' AND end_date < '2013-11-01') // end falls in oct'13
```

This is almost doing the job expect in the case where the start and end dates are outside `Oct'13`. For example, it will miss the rows where the start date is say `2013-05-01` and end date is `2014-02-22`

I'm sure there would be a short and pretty way to use in the `WHERE` than the long approach that I'm following at present. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not clear on what values should be returned. Are you saying return all records that either start or end in october? Or records that start before oct and end after it? Perhaps you could supply some examples.

Comment: @DBC: if you think there is an appropriate answer, please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: I did. Sadly, I can't upvote because of reputation limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about `WHERE start_date < '2013-11-01' And end_date >= '2013-10-01'`

Comment: +1 simplicity at its finest.  If it starts before the end of the month and ends after the start of the month, boom!  Overlap detected for every condition.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more OR

```
WHERE (start_date >= '2013-10-01' AND end_date <= '2013-10-31') OR
    (start_date < '2013-10-01' AND end_date > '2013-10-31')
```